# Request.Form using in two functions

Tags: asp.net, forms, function

I'm creating an online registration system. When user fills the form and clicks on the submit, next page should display that user information.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
    surname.Text = nvc["surname"];
    firstname.Text = nvc["firstname"];
    birth_year.Text = nvc["birth_year"];
    birth_month.Text = nvc["birth_month"];
    birth_day.Text = nvc["birth_day"];
    citizenship.Text = nvc["citizenship"];
    gender.Text = nvc["gender"];
    home_address.Text = nvc["home_address"];
}
```

Comment: I dont know how people insert their code in proper way... :(

Comment: What's the question...?

Comment: I waited 10 mins before downvoted and cast my close vote, you simply didn't ask a question at all!

Answer (score 1):

Creating forms in ASP.Net is relativly simple.  You need only three things on your page:
1.  A forms control:
2.  Some type of control (text box in your example)
3.  A button to submit the request.

First, add the form control to your web page.  This goes in the body section:

```
<form runat="server">
</form>
```

Now, all controls that you want to post back to the server need to be inside that form tag.  Let's add a textbox:

```
<form runat="server">
     <asp:textBox id="lastName" runat="server"></asp:textbox>         
</form>
```

Notice the ID and runat tags.  These are important.  If you want to reference a control in your server pages, you need a unique id.  The runat tag states that the control should be created on the server, instead of the client browser.

Now, add a button to submit:

```
<form runat="server">
     <asp:textBox id="lastName" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
     <asp:Button ID="submit" text="Submit Me" runat="server" OnClick="myEvent_click" />
</form>
```

This control has the same "runat" and "ID" tag as well as a text and OnClick.  The text is just what the button will say in it.  OnClick tells the server what event to call when it posts back.  So, we need to create a "myEvent" event on the server code.  Open up the server code behind (right click and select "View Code").  Add this:

```
Protected Sub myEvent_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
     Dim tbText as string= me.lastName.Text     
End Sub
```

This code will fire when the user presses the submit button.  It creates a variable, of type string, called tbText and assigns it a value from the text in the lastName text box.

All in all, pretty simple.  If you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how can I pass the FORM data form Page1 to PAGE2 in ASP.Net

If I understand your question, you can solve your problem as follows:

in Page1 change the submit button or Register buttons as follows:

```
<asp:Button ID="Register" runat="server" Text="Register"  PostBackUrl="~/PAGE2.aspx" />
```

Good luck